# Does JMeter end up testing the back-end of a web-application with the front-end as an entry point?

Tags: performance, testing, load, jmeter

I'm told that we need to do some performance testing on one of our web-applications, so I'm trying to get some JMeter stuff to work, which as far as I know would simulate the HTTP GETS and POSTS. However, one of my colleagues is telling me that if I use it, it'd only accomplish FE testing. But, if I do this, it still is able to create items in the database and interact with the logic, so I figured it should be sufficient for performance testing of the back-end. Her reasoning is that "if it goes through http pages, we can’t tell which affects the performance".

So am I totally wrong? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of the load testing thing is to simulate real-life users actions and behavior as close to reality as possible.

In JMeter terms that assumes presence and appropriate configuration of the following test elements:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) - to represent browser cookies and deal with cookie-based authentication
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) - to represent browser headers like User-Agent, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Content-Type, etc.
- [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) - browsers download embedded resources like scripts, styles, images, etc. but do it only once, on subsequent requests aforementioned entities are being returned from cache. To simulate this behavior you need to have HTTP Cache Manager
- HTTP Request Samplers need to be configured to fetch embedded resources from the web pages and use a separate thread pool for this. See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for more details on how to configure realistic behavior.

So given JMeter test is good designed and implemented it is quite enough to test backend as well. If during load test you figure out that bottleneck is i.e. database, you may need to load-test the database separately, JMeter is capable of doing this as well, however I'm a strong believer that load testing should be done against environment as close to production as possible and should target the whole system rather than individual components.